# Codeigniter's Active Record IF Statement

Tags: php, database, postgresql, codeigniter

I have a model function like this:

```
function get_dtsample083($dt_date_production,$dt_filler) {
    $this->db1->select('detail_id_sample as detail_id083, detail_id as detail_id_mic, detail_id_sample087_096, headerid_sample, sampling_time, sample_code, product_id, temp, filler, ph, csp_la_35, csp_la_55, tab, operator, remark, rough_mic');
    $this->db1->from('tb_lqs083dtl');
    $this->db1->join('tb_lqs083hdr', 'tb_lqs083hdr.headerid = tb_lqs083dtl.headerid');
    $this->db1->where('tb_lqs083hdr.date_production',$dt_date_production);
    $this->db1->where('tb_lqs083hdr.filler',$dt_filler);

    $try1 = 'Finished Product Coconut Cream';
    $try2 = 'Finished Product';

    if($this->db1->where('tb_lqs083hdr.product_type',$try1)) {
        $this->db1->where('tb_lqs083hdr.product_type',$try1);
        $this->db1->where('tb_lqs083dtl.stdtl','1');
        $this->db1->order_by("tb_lqs083dtl.headerid_sample", "asc");
        $this->db1->order_by("tb_lqs083dtl.detail_id_sample087_096", "asc");
        $this->db1->order_by("tb_lqs083hdr.temp", "asc");        
    } elseif($this->db1->where('tb_lqs083hdr.product_type !=',$try1)) { 
        $this->db1->where('tb_lqs083hdr.product_type',$try2);
        $this->db1->where('tb_lqs083hdr.product_name','Coconut Cream');
        $this->db1->where('tb_lqs083dtl.stdtl','1');
        $this->db1->order_by("tb_lqs083dtl.headerid_sample", "asc");
        $this->db1->order_by("tb_lqs083dtl.detail_id_sample087_096", "asc");
        $this->db1->order_by("tb_lqs083hdr.temp", "asc");
    } else {}

    $query = $this->db1->get();
    echo $this->db1->last_query();
    if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
        return $query->result();
    }
}
```

The first if statement always executed in query execution, i want the second if statement is also being execute.

I have a condition for the query:

- if column `tb_lqs083hdr.product_type = 'Finished Product Coconut Cream'` then first if statement will be execute.
- else if column `tb_lqs083hdr.product_type = 'Finished Product'` then second if statement will be execute.

Both conditions seems similar each other, but in my table both conditions had different values.

I'm still evaluating my query. So any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do an if statement where the conditional is just setting a database call. Since the where statement is always being set, the first condition is always satisfied.

You can solve this in many ways, but you need to address the logic of your code.

You could run a query to find out if 'tb_lqs083hdr.product_type' finds try1 or not. Then use the result of that query in your if statement for your second query.

You could use conditional statements in the query builder:

```
    $this->db->select('*')->from('my_table')
        ->group_start()
            ->where('a', 'a')
            ->or_group_start()
                ->where('b', 'b')
                ->where('c', 'c')
            ->group_end()
        ->group_end()
        ->where('d', 'd')
    ->get();
```

http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html#query-grouping

However, in PHP, if you are writing an if statement it needs to have an argument that could be TRUE or FALSE, otherwise there is not point in having it in your code.

I hope that helps,

Comment: something like this perhaps? See Answer below:

Answer (score 0):

Something like this perhaps?

```
function get_dtsample083($dt_date_production,$dt_filler) {
    $try1 = 'Finished Product Coconut Cream';
    $try2 = 'Finished Product';

    $query = $this->db1->select('detail_id_sample as detail_id083, detail_id as detail_id_mic, detail_id_sample087_096, headerid_sample, sampling_time, sample_code, product_id, temp, filler, ph, csp_la_35, csp_la_55, tab, operator, remark, rough_mic')
        ->from('tb_lqs083dtl')
        ->join('tb_lqs083hdr', 'tb_lqs083hdr.headerid = tb_lqs083dtl.headerid')
        ->where('tb_lqs083hdr.date_production',$dt_date_production)
        ->where('tb_lqs083hdr.filler',$dt_filler)
        ->group_start()
            ->where('tb_lqs083hdr.product_type',$try1)
            ->or_group_start()
                ->where('tb_lqs083hdr.product_type',$try2)
            ->group_end()
        ->group_end()
        ->where('tb_lqs083dtl.stdtl','1')
        ->order_by("tb_lqs083dtl.headerid_sample", "asc")
        ->order_by("tb_lqs083dtl.detail_id_sample087_096", "asc")
        ->order_by("tb_lqs083hdr.temp", "asc") 
    ->get()
}
```